# Joomla Site Overlay

Tags: php, joomla, google-analytics

Does Google's Site overlay  for analytics automatically work for Joomla!? If not how can I make it work.

Comment: Yes. here's the weird part. My site has multiple domains  that point to it. The problem is it works on some but not all.

Answer (score 1):

I've had mixed success with site overlay, the core seems to work well but you can get in to trouble with some components and it really depends on how search engine friendly your site is overall.

The only good answer here is to just try it and see.